# How to fix "request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource" with Appium method ActionChains?

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium, appium-android

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Python 3.10

Windows 10.0.22621

npm 6.13.4

adb Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41

java version "1.8.0_241"

sdkmanager 4.0.1

appium 1.22.3

**PROBLEM:**

I want to click and hold on a smartphone element with Appium and python. I am trying to execute this code:

```
actions = ActionChains(p_driver)
actions.click_and_hold(bottom_right_avatar)
actions.perform()
```

But I get this issue:

```
The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
```

This error message occurs when Python try to execute the last line `"actions.perform()"`
Anyone knows how to fix it please?